# perl not able print desired output

Tags: perl, sqlplus

Hi I am writing a perl script to connect to a DB using SQL Plus but when i query out the data it is not showing proper output, can somebody explain this.

> $ perl test.pl -u user -p paswd -d database

```
while ($ARGV[0] =~ /^-/)
{
        $opt = shift;
        $dbuser = shift if ($opt eq "-u");
        $dbpasswd = shift if ($opt eq "-p");
        $db = shift if ($opt eq "-d");
}
$output=`echo "select sysdate from dual"  | sqlplus  $dbuser\/$dbpasswd\@$db`;
print $output;
```

Output screen: I want output as sysdate.

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Feb 25 13:13:38 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL>   2  Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Comment: Why not use `DBI` and `DBD::Oracle`?

Comment: requirement is like that only

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You showed what you got, but I don't see any error message, and nothing stands out as special. What is it you were expecting?

Comment: Note that your code suffers from multiple code injection bugs.

Comment: Isn't your `SELECT` statement missing the trailing `;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlplus requires many settings to be usable. I suggest:

```
$output=`( echo "set heading off" ; echo "set feedback off" ; echo "set newpage none" ; echo "set pagesize 0" ; echo "select sysdate from dual;" )  | sqlplus -s $dbuser\/$dbpasswd\@$db`;
```

And do not forget to chomp the result:

```
chomp $output
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a `;` missing

```perl
$output=`echo "select sysdate from dual;"  | sqlplus  $dbuser\/$dbpasswd\@$db`;
```